# Same hash function

Tags: android, database, encryption, hash, cryptography

I want to an Android database using a symmetric algorithm (AES).

In cryptography is there a function as below

```
some_function( a-4-digit-PIN, some_salt) {

    return some_hash;

}
```

The 4 digit PIN and salt are complimentary and can vary BUT the function should produce the same hash whichever combination they may be.

The idea is to have the salt stored on the device and the 4 digit PIN sen to the user via text messaging (to support offline situations).

Each user will have his own salt store on the phone (these salts are periodically updated from a central database when the phone can connect to the internet).

The hash produced by this function is used to generate a password for the database, hence why it should always be the same.

In essence, is there a function/algorithms where multiple PIN-salt pairs produce the same a hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` and provide a salt. It will generate a `SecretKey` from your password after some iterations. See in this link a full example of AES encryption and salt generation:

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/03/19/encrypt-decrypt-file-aes-algorithm-android/

```
public static SecretKey generateKey(char[] passphraseOrPin, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
    // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
    // to take >100ms.
    final int iterations = 1000; 

    // Generate a 256-bit key
    final int outputKeyLength = 256;

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    return secretKey;
}
```